# computation of total complexity of an algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

Assume that I have a data sets witch consists of $n$ elements. Then, I apply two algorithms to this set, one after another, and each algorithm has time complexity $O(n^2\log{n})$. What is the oeverall complexity?

My approach is the following. From the one hand side, normally, from what I saw, if the complexity is additive, the we choose the worst one, i.e.
$$
O(\alpha_{n}) + O(\beta_{n}) = O(\alpha_{n}),
$$
if $\alpha_{n}/\beta_{n} \to\infty$, as $n\to\infty$.

At the same time, in our case we have that
$$
n^2\log{n} + n^2\log{n} = 2n^2\log{n} = n^2\log{n^{2}}
$$
Obviously, $\log{n}$ and $\log{n^{2}}$ are different.

What is the solution to my confusion?

Comment: $\log(n)$ and $\log(n^2)$ are the same with respect to complexity. They differ only by a constant factor of $2$. Just as an algorithm that takes $n$ operations and one that takes $10n$ operations are both $O(n)$.

Comment: therefore, the complexity is $O(n^{2}\log(n))$. Correct?

Comment: @Winther , wait... I do not understand... then the complexity is even$O(n^{2}\log(\sqrt{n}))$, since $n^{2}\log(\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2}n^{2}\log(n)$? we can continue to go even more...

Comment: Yes just as an algorithm that takes $1000000000000000000000n$ operations or $10^{10^{100}}n$ is still $O(n)$. The complexity only tells us about how the number of operations scale as we increase $n$ - there is always an implicit constant that it doesn't say anything about so there is no contradiction here.

Comment: why wouldn't you write is as an answer?